# get dictionary of files and directories from git repository

Tags: python, gitpython

I'm trying to get dictionary of directories and files from git repository like this:

```
{"dir1": ["file1", "file2", "dir2", "dir3"], "dir2": {"file3", "dir4"}}
```

I know how to get list of files, the problem is how to transform it into dictionary like this.

My list of files looks like this:

```
["dir/dir1/file1", "dir/dir1/file2", "dir/dir1/dir2/somefile"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feel so stupid now...
I used this code:

```
directories = {'': set()}

for f in files:
    splitted = f.split("/")
    directories[''].add(splitted[0])

    for i in range(len(splitted)):
        if i == len(splitted)-1:
            break

        d = ''
        for j in splitted[0:i+1]:
            d += j + os.path.sep

        d = d[0:-1]

        if not d in directories:
            directories[d] = set()

        directories[d].add(splitted[i+1])
```